# file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php

```
<?php
include '../database/db.php';
if(isset($_POST['email1'])){
$email=$_POST['email1'];
$caption= $_POST['caption'];
 //upload image
 $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  if (!isset($file)) {
  }else{
  $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($file));
  $image_name= addslashes($file);
  $image_size= getimagesize($file);}
    if ($image_size=="") {
      die(mysql_error());}
    else{
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../pics/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
      $images="../pics/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
  //Create query
  $sql="INSERT INTO pic (filename,email,caption) VALUES '`$images`'``,'$email',``'`$caption`')`"`;
if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  echo '<script>alert("Please rename your picture only letters or numbers are valid");</script>';
  }
echo '<iis_get_script_map(server_instance, virtual_path, script_extension)>alert("Successfully Uploaded!"); window.location="home.php";</script>';
}
}
else{
    die(mysql_error());
}
 ?>
```

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty on line 15
>
> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty on line 17

Comment: Even though you don't have an actual question. Check the form to see if all the essentials are set up. example: `enctype="multipart/form-data">` is in your opening `form` tag etc.

Comment: that code is crap. full of syntax errors, cargo-cult programming. bad assumptions, [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilityes, horrible code constructs, yada yada yada. in short, nuke it from orbit, and start again.

Comment: @andre3wap yes i put `enctype="multipart/form-data">` in my form. sorry im new in php.

Comment: @jayson - can we see your from's html code please.

Comment: <form action="savepic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="email1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>" />
        <table style="border:.5px solid #333;">
         <tr>
          <th style="border:1px solid #78B6EA;"><input type="file" name="image"/></th>
          
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <th><textarea style="width:320px;" name="caption" type="text" placeholder="Caption"></textarea></th>
          <th><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></th>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </form>

Comment: thank you @andre3wap for helping me.

Comment: @andre3wap i change it but there's a problem Notice: Undefined index: image
Notice: Undefined variable: image_size

Comment: actually its function is ok. but sometimes if i upload some image with a un "_" in filename. there is always an error.